# How to copy the label text of a radio button to another radio button using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how to achieve this with jQuery? I started studying it recently but I really can't make anything work.

To make it clearer:

I have this account on one website that has this ask box inside an iframe. It has a radio box in it that has a picture and some text that varies according to the viewer of the page.

What I want to do is fetch that radio box's label text using jQuery so I can duplicate the radio box.

Is that possible?

Comment: can we have some html markup please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume html as below..

```
   <input type="radio" name="r1" id="rad1"><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="r2" id="rad2"><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
```

Then here is the code to get the label text value associated to radio button..

```
   $(':radio').each(function()
   {
      var target=$(this).attr('id');
      target = $('label[for="' + target + '"]').html();
      // Here you can write further code.. 
   });
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RqDD/2/) is the fiddle for demo.